# Space efficient DAGs in SQL without recursive queries?

Tags: sql

The standard way to represent DAGs in SQL is the transitive closure table:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (Id int primary key identity, Name nvachar(30))
CREATE TABLE Foo_Foo
(ParentId int not null
,ChildId int not null
,Distance int not null)
```

So every parent-child relation inserted requires duplicating all of the parent's Foo_Foo entries with Distance + 1:

```
INSERT INTO Foo (Name) VALUES ('Some Name')
DECLARE @somename int = @@IDENTITY

-- DAG: Some Name -> Some other name
INSERT INFO Foo (Name) VALUES ('Some other name')
DECLARE @someother int = @@IDENTITY
INSERT INTO Foo_Foo (ParentId, ChildId, Distance)
VALUES (@somename, @someother, 0)

-- DAG: Some Name -> Some other name -> Some final name
INSERT INTO Foo (Name) Values ('Some final name')
INSERT INTO Foo_Foo (ParentId, ChildId, Distance)
VALUES (@someother, @@IDENTITY, 0)
INSERT INTO Foo_Foo (ParentId, ChildId, Distance) 
SELECT ParentId, @@IDENTITY, Distance + 1 FROM Foo_Foo
WHERE ChildId = @someother

-- DAG: Some Name -> Some other name -> Some final name
--               \_____________________/
INSERT INTO Foo_Foo (ParentId, ChildId, Distance)
VALUES (@someother, @@IDENTITY, 0)
```

The problem is that the Foo_Foo table grows with the factorial of the DAG path depth times the number of unique paths, ie. every Foo inserted at distance D from a root vertex V of the DAG requires at least (# unique paths to D from V) * (D-1) * (D-2) * ... entries in the Foo_Foo table. I can normalize the above even further to get space complexity (~# vertices at distance D from V) * (D-1)!, but that's as good as I could get it.

This is clearly infeasible for representing DAGs that can grow arbitrarily long. Recursive queries are the probably the best solution, but aren't fully supported everywhere. Trees have some some clever solutions, but I haven't been able to find a good solution for DAGs. Are there any clever DAG solutions using SQL tables with non recursive queries?

Comment: You need a solution for standard/generic SQL, rather than in specific product(s)?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for a representation of DAGS in generic SQL, like the closure/join table.